# Why are non auto-generated document Ids are in italics in Firestore console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

When i add a document with my own document Id (not auto generated), document Id node is in italics as shown in the screenshot from Firestore console. What is the reason behind this?

My code to add data is

```js
const billingRef = db
      .collection('billing/test/2017/months/11')
      .doc();

  billingRef
      .set({ name: 'ABC' })
      .then(_ => {
        console.log('saved');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Above code adds a node successfully, but adds node "test" and "months" in italics.

screenshot 1
[image]

screenshot 2
[image]
screenshot 3
[image]

My query yields zero results for such records in firestore, following code. How can I query all the nodes under billing?

```js
db.collection("billing").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    console.log(querySnapshot.size) // this is always 0
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't know the actual cause, but it isn't about the ID being auto-generated or not as far as I can tell. I just added a doc with a self-typed ID, and it showed up non-italic, same as all the other (auto-generated) IDs in the list.

Comment: Note that you're mixing two separate questions here: 1. Why are some document IDs showing as italic in the console? 2. Why doesn't my code return any documents? I recommend posting each as a separate question, as the answers might have little to do with each other.

Comment: For question 2: do you have permission to read from `/billing`? Easiest way to detect that is to add `.catch((function(error) { console.error(error); })`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Frank, I believe the questions are related because this happens only for document IDs in italics. I have updated my question with the code to show how I add the records to firestore turns document IDs in italic. I have consistently reproduced this behaviour.

Comment: If `test` in `billing/test/2017/months/11` ref does not exists in Firestore, try using the `add()` method to add the doc first before referencing to it.

Comment: Nobody knows still what's the preblem?

Comment: What I have noticed is that when you set data in your Firestore through code, if you add a Document ("test" and "months") that ONLY contains a Collection ("2017" and "11"), then they will be in italic. The moment you add a Field to "test" and "months" the italic will be removed. My intuition (which may be wrong) is if the Document is "initialised" only with a Collection and no Fields, then it is seen like "null" (italic) (lack of better word), but if a Field is added, and also removed, then it is simply empty (no italic).

Comment: For **question 1**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48138953/2162226 - Thanks @Frank

Comment: You can not access data of null doc. But You can access sub-collection of null doc. As it returns **doc.id** , So you can complete your path to sub-collection

Answer (score 26):

Following up on my comment above you will see in the Firestore console that for Documents in **italic** there is a small text saying **"This document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or snapshots"**, for **non-italic** it says **"This document has no data"**, so the intuition is that when the Document is created in code without any Fields then it is "null" (a subcollection does not count). If a Field is added and removed, then the Document is simply empty and not null.

Since your query for the Documents under billing are in italic ("null" or does not exist), as the text above states, they will not appear in queries.

The solution would be to either add the document through the Firestore console because here Documents are created as empty, or if in code, add a Field and maybe remove it again if not needed, then the Documents will appear in queries.

Answer (score 5):

The problem, I later came to find from this Question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137582/firestore-db-documents-shown-in-italics/48138953#48138953) for me was creating a sub collection to an empty document. This was my code that was bringing up grayed out documents.

```
       db.collection('temporal')
            .doc('documentexample')
            .collection("files")
            .add({
              name: "Lorem"
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error("Error adding file: ", error);
            });
```

In the above code the doc `documentexample` had no field in it. So the code goes ahead and creates `documentexample` (it has no fields) then creates a subCollection in it `files`. This according to firebase just grays out the first document `documentexample`.

The workaround to this is first create the document add a field in it then create a subcollection to it and on and on... For my use-case, I created a function that creates the document and adds a field to it when the user signs up for the first time

Comment: Was looking everywhere for a solution, thank you for this