# Two Document having same documentId in Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have root collection, inside that two documents having the same Document Id. The first document having data and the second is in italic format. On click of the second document, it will navigate to an error page saying that the project does not exist or either you do not have permission. Attaching a screenshot for reference.
It showing two document with the same DocumentId first in normal case and second in Italic. "Maharashtra", "*Maharashtra*".
[image]

Comment: how two documents having the same document Id, and not able to delete the second document i.e."Maharashtra"

Answer (score 1):

At some point in the past, you have deleted the document "Maharashtra" without recursively deleting it's child collections.

These collections are still present in your database but not currently attached to the parent document. As an example, the document `"/states/Maharashtra/logs/day1"` might exist with data, while it's parent collection `"/states/Maharashtra/logs"` is not a part of the current document `"/states/Maharashtra"`.

You should be able to expand the italicised entry to see it's orphaned sub-collections.

[@puf explained it better here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48138953/3068190).