# get data from all the docs of firebase in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

i want indivisualscore of all the ids to get printed on the console.

when i search for each indivisual id passed it gives me correct answer. for example

```
 CollectionReference collectionReference =  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('score');
    await collectionReference.doc(widget.uid).collection("indivisualscore").snapshots().listen((event) {
      print(event.docs.length);
    }
```

here i am passing widget.uid, gives me indivisualscore of that particular id passed.

but i now want to obtain indivisualscore of all the ids, in the score collection.
it has to do something with the length of the doc in score collection,but i am not able to get it correctly.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the ids inside the collection `score`, then you have to do the following:

```
CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('score');
var snapshot = await collectionReference.get();
 snapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
    print(result.id);
  });
```

Reference the collection `score` then use `get()` to obtain the documents inside that collection, then the property `docs` will return a `List<DocumentSnapshot>` which you can iterate and get all the ids.

Comment: where did you paste it?

Comment: if it is not printing, then its not even entering it.. you have to debug it to check

Comment: but for indivisual uid,its printing. i debugged it,and its running your code, but not printing anything.

Comment: printing  print(snapshot.docs); shows empty erray in the console, and printing just snapshort gives Instance of 'QuerySnapshot' in console

Comment: printing snapshort.size prints 0, how is it even possible?

Comment: are the document id deleted?

Comment: check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/using-console#non-existent_ancestor_documents it seems you deleted the documents since they are in italics according to your image

Comment: have you setup any rules at Firestore console?

Comment: @Yadu the documents are deleted, check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/using-console#non-existent_ancestor_documents *the document at path `/mycoll/mydoc/mysubcoll/mysubdoc` can exist even if the ancestor document `/mycoll/mydoc` does not.*

Comment: @Yadu check the documents id here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64890658/how-to-set-documentid-in-firestore-using-flutter

Comment: @PeterHaddad if i am using your code on other collection, its working fine, but on this particular collection that is score, ids get saved in italics, and it doesnt respond to the code,

Comment: delete the whole score collection, start again, and it will work. All the score collection deleted it until there is no "score" (delete from console)

Comment: No, you cannot query for collection that are inside of another document in one go, only multiple **documents** in a single collection can be queried, `individualScore` is collection inside a document (which has been deleted as peter noted), correct me if I am wrong

Comment: guys, comment wasnt deleted, i learnt that we cannot only keep the collection in the doc, there has to be something in the doc apart from that collection. for more info,check @K.vijaiarivalagan comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137582/firestore-db-documents-shown-in-italics

Comment: appreciate @PeterHaddad for pointing the error,thankyou so much