# How to set documentID in firestore using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am trying to set my documentID manually in my flutter application but it keeps creating a new field inside my document named DocumentID. How do I set my documented?

```
  final barcode = TextEditingController();
  final price = TextEditingController();
  final stock = TextEditingController();
  final color = TextEditingController();
  ///the above are textformfield controllers I use for the data input
  addData() {
    Map<String, dynamic> theData = {
      //"DocumentID" : barcode.text,
      "Color" : color.text,
      "Price" : price.text,
      "Stock" : stock.text,
    };
    CollectionReference collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("products");
    collectionReference.add(theData);
  }
  addID(){
    DocumentReference dataID = Firestore.instance.document("products");
    dataID.set(DocumentReference, barcode.text);
  }
```

The data also displays only "" in my database when using the method addData:
[image]

Below is mu adjusted code:

```
  final barcode = TextEditingController();
  final price = TextEditingController();
  final stock = TextEditingController();
  final color = TextEditingController();
  addData() {
    Map<String, dynamic> theData = {
      "Color" : color.text,
      "Price" : price.text,
      "Stock" : stock.text,
    };
    CollectionReference collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("products");
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("products").doc(barcode.text).set(theData);
    collectionReference.add(theData);

  }
```

I get this error:
[image]

Comment: its creating a documentid because you have this `//"DocumentID" : barcode.text,` probably wasn't commented

Answer (score 1):

you can set it like this

```
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("products").doc("my_own_document_id").set(data);
```

you can set the document id while creating it, but you cannot change it

Comment: Does the hintText/Labeltext interfere with anything?

Comment: How can I input barcode.text because its a textformfield so the page has to load first, maybe add await to the method?

Comment: format the question for the answer provided, ask new question on it