# Cloud Firestore doesn't retrive assigned document Id in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase collection named `Rooms` and sub-collection `messages` but when I try to retrieve the `Rooms` collection it only returns the generated document IDs.

I have tried to retrieve it with this code. but it only retrieves the generated document IDs.

```
final data = await firestore.collection('Rooms').get(); 
for (var doc in data.docs) {
    final event = doc.id;
    print(event);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. What do you expect this code to print? And what does it print instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
final data = await firestore.collection('Rooms').get(); 
for (var doc in data.docs) {
    final id = doc.id;
    final data = doc.data();
    print(id);     // it return the Document ID
    print(data);   // it return the Document data
}
```

I am not sure which ID you want to access by the above code, if you created an `id` field manually, follow the below instructions.

> **final data = doc.data();**
> This allows access to the fields created within each document like `data['id']`

Comment: I appreciate your response. but,  In my Room collection on Firebase, I've encountered something unexpected. There are two types of document IDs: one is italicized (manually assigned ID), and the other is the usual generated document ID.  The code you provided only retrieves documents with the generated IDs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to those who give me the response to my question.
I got the answer from this post.

[The data I added to Firestore is displayed in italic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75283001/the-data-i-added-to-firestore-is-displayed-in-italic)

The italics style only means that under this document, there are other subcollections present. If you try to query such documents, you won't get a result, since such documents don't exist. So that document is displayed like that for two main reasons. You either deleted the document without deleting all the documents in all of their subcollections, or you didn't create it in the first place.