# Firestore id naming convention

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any naming convention for document id in FireStore. I created some documents inside a collection with the date in "yyyy-mm-dd" as the id. When i try to get all documents inside the collection i got the snapshot size as zero. When I put a dummy doc with test as id I got only the test doc not the other docs.

My document structure

[image: firestore structure]

Comment: post your code so we could see where is the problem

Comment: Figured out the problem. Its not the naming convention. Its because documents has no fields inside.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731794/why-are-non-auto-generated-document-ids-are-in-italics-in-firestore-console

Answer (score 3):

The contraints can be seen here [Quotas and Limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) if you scroll down to the bottom you will find contraints on ids, paths and field names.