# Get the document IDs from a collections firestore - Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I have a nested collection/document Firestore DB:

```
/events/evtid/users/user
 Coll  Docs  Coll  Docs
```

I am trying to get the document ids from `evtid` documents using the below script:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

# Use a service account.
cred = credentials.Certificate('mycredentials.json')

app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

coll = db.collection("events").stream()

for doc in coll:
    print(f'{doc.id}')
```

But nothing is presented. If I put an id for an especific document in `evtid` and the subcollection `users` ->

`coll = db.collection("events").document("someid").collection("users").stream()`

then it gets the documents (user). I don't know the ids for the documents in `evtid` and I first need to find them out.

What am I doing wrong?

A screenshot how the structure looks like
[image]

Comment: Can you also provide the snapshot of your DB as that will give an idea of how your db structure looks like

Comment: @RohitKharche please check the image attached to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I can see in your Firestore database snapshot, apparently there are no documents in the `events` collection.

The reason for this is that the document IDs in that collection are in italics, which usually means that the main documents have been deleted, but the subcollections within them still exist. As a result, you can retrieve documents from the `users` subcollections, but not from the `events` collection.

The fact that you are able to see the deleted documents ids is because You just have `users` subcollection under document IDs, which causes the Firebase console to show the document IDs of the `events` collection, so that you can select them.

If you want to backfill that deleted data with new one without disturbing the `users` subcollection then you can use a [**collection group query**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) on `users` subcollection, loop through those results, and write the parent document with something like

```
document.ref.parent.parent.set({ user: "Bob", age: 18 })
```

Reference :

- [Firestore DB - documents shown in italics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137582/firestore-db-documents-shown-in-italics)

Also check :

- [Firestore query returns no documents even though they are shown in the console in italics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70539283/20239914)