# how to retrieve the unknown documents(each document contains collection named Messages that have message documents) from subcollection in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This is the code where I'm trying to fetch the docs Ids but it returns no documents found.

subcollection chats contain documents based on each product id and that document contains a collection of known Messages that has documents of each message. Below are the images of Firestore.
There is a user collection that contains user ids based on each user id(current) I'm trying to access the subcollection and that subcollection contains documents based on each product id on which chat is done and then there are documents that contain messages.

Image1:
[image: Image1 of cloud firestore]

Image2:
[image: Image2 of cloud firestore]

Here is the code:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Subcollection Documents'),
  ),
  body: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .collection('Chats')
        .get(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Center(
          child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
        );
      } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final documents = snapshot.data!.docs;
        return ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          primary: true,
          itemCount: documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final docId = documents[index].id;
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(docId),
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        return const Center(
          child: Text('No documents found.'),
        );
      }
    },
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully in both screenshots, you can see that the document ID in the `Chats` is printed in *italics*. This means that there is not actually a document at that path in the database, and the console only shows that ID because there is a collection underneath it (in your case the `Messages` collection).

Since there is no actual document in the `Chats` collection, this code will get no results:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(user!.uid)
    .collection('Chats')
    .get(),
```

To address the problem, make sure that you create an actual document inside the `Chats` collection. You don't necessarily need to put any data in it, but the document must exist in order to be able to read it with your query.

Also see:

- [Firestore DB - documents shown in italics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137582/firestore-db-documents-shown-in-italics)
- [Why are non auto-generated document Ids are in italics in Firestore console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731794/why-are-non-auto-generated-document-ids-are-in-italics-in-firestore-console)
- [Firestore query returns no documents even though they are shown in the console in italics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70539221/firestore-query-returns-no-documents-even-though-they-are-shown-in-the-console-i)