# Firestore only returning one document from collection despite having multiple docs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch all documents from a Firestore collection using Node.js. I have multiple documents in the collection, but when I run my code, it only returns one document. Here's my code:

```js
const {
  initializeApp,
  cert,
} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {
  getFirestore,
} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

const serviceAccount = require("./service-account.json");
initializeApp({
  credential: cert(serviceAccount),
});

const db = getFirestore();
const orgsCollection = db.collection("orgs");

const getAllDocs = async () => {
  const querySnapshot = await orgsCollection.get();
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
  });
};

getAllDocs().catch(console.error);

// 1 => {} --- output
```

I've already checked the following:

The service account has the appropriate permissions.
The documents are indeed in the orgs collection and not a subcollection.

The documents exist at the time of querying.
There's no pagination or query constraints applied that could be limiting the results.

I'm not using any complex queries, so I don't think indexing is the issue. Can anyone suggest why I might not be getting all my documents?

following is my database schema:

[image: database schema]

I expect my code to log all documents in the orgs collection to the console. Each document should be logged in the format:

```
1 => { ...document data... }
1511 => { ...document data... }
1665 => { ...document data... }
1677 => { ...document data... }
20 => { ...document data... }
22 => { ...document data... }
39 => { ...document data... }
95 => { ...document data... }
99 => { ...document data... }
```

Comment: We can't see the contents of your database, and you haven't explained what exactly this program is expected to output instead, so we can't tell what's wrong here.  You should edit the question to provide enough information that someone can use to fully duplicate the behavior you observe.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks! I added the schema and expected output

Answer (score 1):

Your collection has only one document in it.  We can tell because only the "1" document is in a normal font.  All the others are in italics, which means they don't exist (but they have at least one nested subcollection - the present document ID in italics is just something for you to click on to navigate into them).  So your code is working as expected.

See also:

- [Firestore DB - documents shown in italics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137582/firestore-db-documents-shown-in-italics)
- [Why are non auto-generated document Ids are in italics in Firestore console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731794/why-are-non-auto-generated-document-ids-are-in-italics-in-firestore-console)

Also from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/using-console#non-existent_ancestor_documents):

> In a collection's list of documents, the document IDs of non-existent ancestor documents are italicized.